# jump effect while moving rotated rectangle

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

I am preparing a logic for a simple tank battle game. The idea is that you have a tank (rectangle). By pushing `a` or `d` you rotate it, while pushing `w` or `s` - moves it up(front) or down (back).

```
if(keys[65] === true) {
    gun.angle -= gun.speed;
}

if(keys[68] === true) {
    gun.angle += gun.speed;
}

if(keys[87] === true) {
    gun.x += gun.speed * Math.cos(radians(gun.angle));
    gun.y += gun.speed * Math.sin(radians(gun.angle));
}

if(keys[83] === true) {
    gun.x -= gun.speed * Math.cos(radians(gun.angle));
    gun.y -= gun.speed * Math.sin(radians(gun.angle));
}
```

the script works pretty nice but there is one issue i have hard time solving. If you rotate tank there is no problem but when you move up or down, there is jump effect.

When you move up it jumps down, while when you move down it jumps up.

It can easily be tested with this [demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebz32k01/). i suspect that problem may be related to a fact that the points affected by moving are `x` and `y` of the tank while the translations (for rotating) are based on center point of the tank. I dont know how to fix it.

Any help would be nice ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the animate function, you are calculating the gun center before updating the gun position. As a result, the tank's gun (i.e. circle and line) is drawn at the old location but the tank's body (i.e. rectangle) is drawn at the new location while the tank is moving.

Change...

```
var animate = function() {

    gun_center_x = gun.x + (gun.w / 2);
    gun_center_y = gun.y + (gun.h / 2);

    if(keys[65] === true) {
        gun.angle -= gun.speed;
    }

    if(keys[68] === true) {
        gun.angle += gun.speed;
    }

    if(keys[87] === true) {
        gun.x += gun.speed * Math.cos(radians(gun.angle));
        gun.y += gun.speed * Math.sin(radians(gun.angle));
    }

    if(keys[83] === true) {
        gun.x -= gun.speed * Math.cos(radians(gun.angle));
        gun.y -= gun.speed * Math.sin(radians(gun.angle));
    }

    ...

};
```

to...

```
var animate = function() {


    if(keys[65] === true) {
        gun.angle -= gun.speed;
    }

    if(keys[68] === true) {
        gun.angle += gun.speed;
    }

    if(keys[87] === true) {
        gun.x += gun.speed * Math.cos(radians(gun.angle));
        gun.y += gun.speed * Math.sin(radians(gun.angle));
    }

    if(keys[83] === true) {
        gun.x -= gun.speed * Math.cos(radians(gun.angle));
        gun.y -= gun.speed * Math.sin(radians(gun.angle));
    }

    gun_center_x = gun.x + (gun.w / 2);
    gun_center_y = gun.y + (gun.h / 2);

    ...

};
```